# Compare each element of a variable within each group

Tags: r

Consider the data frame in R:

```
set.seed(36)

y <- runif(10,0,200)
group <- sample(rep(1:2, each=5))
d <- data.frame(y, group)
```

I want to compare all `y` against all `y` within each group. The following codes do this correctly:

```
d_split <- split(d, d$group)
a <- with(d_split[[1]],outer(y, y, "<="))
b <- with(d_split[[2]],outer(y, y, "<="))
```

But while I am doing this inside a function, and the number of group varies (`group` will be an argument of that function), then I cannot proceed in this manner. How can I elegantly write the last three line codes to compare all `y` against all `y` within each group?

Comment: Convert your last three lines into `lapply(split(d, d$group), function(x) outer(x[["y"]], x[["y"]], "<="))`. Would also work for multiple groups.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option without `split`ting

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[, as.data.table(outer(y, y, "<=")), group]
#    group    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
#1:     1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#2:     1 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#3:     1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#4:     1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#5:     1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#6:     2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#7:     2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#8:     2  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#9:     2 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#10:    2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

---

Or in a 'long' format with `CJ`

```
setDT(d)[, CJ(y, y), group][, V1 <= V2, group]
```

Comment: Could you please tell in `setDT(d)[, as.data.table(outer(y, y, "<=")), group]` if I want to do some calculation with the columns but don't want to change the elements of the `group`  column, how can I do that? For example, if `dt <- setDT(d)[, as.data.table(outer(y, y, "<=")), group]` and I want add value 2 with each elements of each column except the `group` column, how can I do that?

Comment: @Leaf Did you meant `setDT(d)[, as.data.table(outer(y, y, "<=")) + 2, group]`

Comment: Okay, it's working. But I am actually trying to do something like that:  `dt1 <- setDT(d)[, as.data.table(outer(y, y, "<=")), group]`;  `dt2 <- setDT(d)[, as.data.table(outer(y, y, ">")), group]`. Now I am trying to multiply each element of `dt1` with each element of `dt2`. But don't want to change the value of the `group` column. But simply doing `dt1 * dt2`  changes group #2 into #4.

Comment: @Leaf Where do you want to update?  Is it in 'dt1' or 'dt2"?

Comment: @Leaf If you are updating 'dt1' then `for(j in 2:ncol(dt1)){
 set(dt1, i = NULL, j = j, value = dt1[[j]]*dt2[[j]])
 }`

Answer (score 4):

To perform the same operation for multiple groups we can use `lapply` and perform the `outer` operation for every group.

```
lapply(split(d, d$group), function(x) outer(x[["y"]], x[["y"]], "<="))

#$`1`
#      [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#[1,]  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,]  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#[4,]  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#[5,]  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

#$`2`
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4]  [,5]
#[1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
#[3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE
#[5,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE TRUE  TRUE
```